# Disable keyboard individual letters pop-up

Tags: android, keyboard

Does anybody know how to programmatically disable the keyboard individual letter pop-up?

(This blue pop-up when you click in a letter on the virtual keyboard of the device.)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this from an application.

If the keyboard on a device is built to do this, the only option you have is to build/install/use a different keyboard that doesn't do it.

Applications are not capable of manipulating the system keyboard (except for small things like ime options, inputType etc.)

Answer (score 1):

In your phone, go to Settings --> Language and Input --> Select the keyboard type that you are using. (In my case it says Samsung keyboard). Select the settings icon next to it. There is an option called "Character preview". Disable it.